# How is the Satellite view implemented in the detail view controller, displayed upon touch of a MKPinAnnotation Callout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit

In the apple maps app if you tap on a MKPinAnnotation callout, the following view is displayed. Im trying to recreate something similar, but I'm unsure how to implement the satellite image (I assume it's a MKMapView over the coordinates of the annotation selected)and how to animated the stretch of the satellite view when the view beneath is pulled down? Also The satellite view constantly rotates back and forwards is this a standard animation?

In summary:

- How is the map image at the top implemented?
- How is it stretched/zoomed when the user drags the bottom(table) view down
- How is the image animated so that it rotates, is it a built in feature?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the map image at the top implemented?

This is not a image. This is a MKMapView.

> How is it stretched/zoomed when the user drags the bottom(table) view down

Update mapview.frame.size.height when scroll with scrollView.contentOffest.y.

> How is the image animated so that it rotates, is it a built in feature?

MKMapView [setCamera:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setCamera:animated:) or animate MKMapView.camera

I made a sample you can download [here](https://github.com/powhu/SampleMapDetail).